# What does locking an SMS message do?

Tags: sms

I have noticed that long clicking an SMS message brings up a menu containing a "Lock message" option. What does this do? I have a Nexus S.

Comment: Presumably it prevents you from deleting it, but you'd need to be clearer about what kind of messages you're talking about and what phone/app you have.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Nexus S. SMS messages

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you lock a message, when you delete a conversation with a locked message, every message other than the locked message will be erased from that conversation.

Answer (score 5):

On most android smartphones there is a feature that makes the phone run faster. This feature is after a certain amount of messages(on mine it's 210)it begins to delete them,locking the message also prevents it from being deleted.

Answer (score 2):

that means (normally on every phone) that it cannot be deleted, just like a locked picture on a camera. so, if you would like to keep a message safe, i suggest locking it so no accidents happen. although, when the time comes that it wants to be deleted, it can be unlocked and then deleted